# Mini electric guitar tuning

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, tuning

To make it short, I am in the military and I try to take a guitar every time I am deployed. The thing is I can't take much with me so I need a very (very very) small guitar. I have a LAG guitalele (basically a uke with 6 strings), normally tuned in A, but a use Cordoba Mini E strings, specially made to have short instruments tuned in E. Recently I found this very small electric guitar, the Fazley Niño, with an integrated amp that works on battery. It's between an electric guitalele, a kid electric guitar and a toy, but it will do the trick when I am somewhere in the desert and I wanna play something. But it is also tuned in A and I would also like to tune it in E... I can't find special strings like the ones on my guitalele, the mini E strings being only for acoustic instruments (nylon strings). I can go down to F sharp without it being sloppy. Anyone has an idea or a trick so I can tune it down to E? (extra tension strings maybe?)

Thanks!

Comment: Knowing the length of open strings would help us answer.

Comment: Right. 500mm /19,68 inches

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need heavier-gauge strings.

The physics behind this is that, for a given length and tension, heavier strings vibrate more slowly because they have more mass per unit length.[This article, "Ultimate guide to guitar scale length"](https://guitargearfinder.com/guides/ultimate-guide-to-guitar-scale-length/), has more details.